# Работа кэш-памяти

Tags: кэширование

Пусть кэш имеет 4 банка ассоциативности, каждый рамером 16 байтов. В программе реализован цикл, который каждую итерацию обращается последовательно к ячейкам по адресам 8, 24, 40, 56, 72, 88. Будет ли иметь место буксование кэша и почему?

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю, подвох в вопросе в том, что диапазон 8-24 это не 16, а 17 байт. Ну, и в остальных случаях тоже. Потребуется 6 загрузок на цикл.

Соответственно, будет "буксовать"))

Comment: Почему 6 загрузок?

Comment: Я вроде всё расписал. При обращении к ячейке 8 будет загружен диапазон 8-23 (это 16 байт). Ячейка 24 в него не попадает. Ну и т.д.